# How authentic is the story of the spider web at the cave of Thawr?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, hijra

Today I've come across this [story](http://www.beliefnet.com/love-family/parenting/2000/09/teaching-tales-king-david-and-the-spider.aspx):

> ...
> At last, the soldiers were very close. David ran into a cave to hide.
> He heard the footsteps of the men and knew that they would soon find
> him. David was so afraid, his bones shook and hurt.
>
> But then David saw a big spider at the front of the cave. Very
> quickly, it was spinning a web all the way across the opening. Just
> before the soldiers came up to the cave, the spider finished the web.
> As the men started to enter the cave, they ran into the web. "Look,"
> they said, "This web is unbroken. If David were here, he'd have torn
> the web to pieces. He must be hiding somewhere else. Let's go!"

It bears striking resemblance to the following [story](http://aboutislam.net/family-society/moms-dads/prophet-spider-story-hijrah/) that is believed to took place during Hijrah, well known by most of the Muslims:

> ...
> Their Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) was accompanied by his
> best friend started their journey in the depths of the night. They
> managed to leave Makkah, despite being hunted down. They hid in a
> cave. It was late at night and they were in danger. Alhamdulillah,
> Allah is the Most Merciful. Even while in the cave, they were nearly
> caught by the Quraysh…their assassins who were hot on their heels.
> Then there was a spider. It spun a web to protect Prophet Muhammad and
> Abu Bakr Siddique. The Quraysh people came and they saw a spider’s web
> worth days and days of work. So there was no doubt that the two men
> could have hidden in the cave without such a large spider web in front
> of it.

I wonder what scholars think of the Muslim version of the story. Do they deem it as a fabrication/part of Isra'illiyat or as authentic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This story does not have any authentic hadith that validates it.

The story of the cave of *Thawr* is one such story that the chain of narration was not strictly scrutinized by some scholars. It was narrated through ['Abdullah ibn 'Abbās](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_Allah_ibn_Abbas) and documented by Ibn Hanbal in his *Musnad* ([hadith 3251](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/2310)).

This hadith was graded as *hassan* (good) by [Ibn Hajar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-%60Asqalani) in *Fat'h al-Bārī* ([gloss of hadith 887](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7447/484)) and [Ibn Kathir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Kathir) in *As-Sīrah an-Nabawiyyah* ([Vol. 2, pp. 239](https://al-maktaba.org/book/930/766)) and in *Al-Bidāya wa an-Nihāyah* ([Vol. 4, pp. 451](https://al-maktaba.org/book/4445/2161)), and and it was graded as *da'īf* (weak) bu [Al-Albani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Nasiruddin_al-Albani) in *Silsilat al-Ahādith ad-Da'īfa wa al-Mawdū'a* ([Vol. 13, pp. 741](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12762/11747). Needless to say, it was documented in multiple books, more than what can be listed in a single answer, but these are the major commentaries on its authenticity.

The hadith is narrated through Abdur-Razzāq through Ma'mar through 'Uthmān al-Jarazi through Miqsam through Ibn 'Abbās. 'Uthmān al-Jarazi (Arabic: عثمان الجزري) is considered weak in hadith by Ibn Abi Hātim in *Al-Jarh wa at-Ta'dīl* (Vol. 6, pp. 174) and that only Ma'mar and An-Nu'mān narrated through him. Ibn Hanbal said that he had multiple weak narrations. It seems that considering the hadith as da'īf (weak) is the stronger opinion due to 'Uthmān al-Jarazi being in the narration, the opinion with which most other scholars of hadith agree.

The governing principle for such stories is what [Imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmad_ibn_Hanbal) said in *Al-Kefāya*:

> إذا روينا عن رسول الله -صلى الله عليه وسلم- في الحلال والحرام والسنن والأحكام تشدَّدنا في الأسانيد، وإذا روينا عن النبي -صلى الله عليه وسلم- في فضائل الأعمال، وما لا يضع حكمًا أو يرفعه تساهلنا في الأسانيد
>
> <sub>*— **NOTE**: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> If we get narrations of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ about *halāl* and *harām*, we are very strict about narration chains. If we get narrations of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ about virtues of deeds and what does not have associated rulings, we are more lenient on narration chains.

On another note, the hadith has different versions documented in *Musnad Abi Bakr* and *Kashf al-Astār*. The hadith in *Musnad Abi Bakr* has Ibn Mūssa ash-Shaybani (Arabic: بشار بن موسى الشيباني الخفاف) in its chain of narration, and his hadith is forsaken for being *munkar* (according to Yahya ibn Ma'īn, An-Nasā'i, Ibn Hajar, and others), in addition to the hadith being *mursal* with one member of the chain of narration missing (and even considered *mu'dal* by some scholars, i.e., missing two consecutive members in the chain of narration). The hadith in *Kashf al-Astār* is a different version that refers to a pigeon establishing its nest and laying its eggs at the entrance of the cave in addition to the spider's web. This hadith was also deemed *da'īf* at best and was graded *munkar* by Al-Albani. It has two unknown men in its chain: 'Awn ibn 'Umair (Arabic: عون بن عمير) and Abu Mus'ab (Arabic: أبو مصعب). The men in the chain of narration were deemed unacceptable by Yahya ibn Ma'īn, Al-Bukhāri, Adh-Dhahabi, Ibn Kathir, and others.